# "provide" keyword in Jasmine, Angular2 RC.4 upgrade - "Deprecated symbol used"

Tags: typescript, angular, jasmine

I just upgraded my Angular2 app to use Angular2-rc-4 and after making some amends thanks to the console my IDE (IntelliJ) is telling me that the `provide`keyword is depreciated? The keyword now has a strikethrough and when hovering I am given the message 'Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative'. Okay, I guess, however I didn't see or read anything about this is the release notes?

So in my tests I had the following...

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provideRouter(routes, MockLocationStrategy),
    MyTestComponent,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' }),
    provide(ContentService, {useClass: MockContentService})
]);
```

I looked at the release notes and changed it to the following

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
        provideRouter(routes, SpyLocation),
        MyTestComponent,
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' }),
        provide(ContentService, {useClass: MockContentService})
    ]));
```

Does anyone know what I should or how I should replace my `provide` statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was changed to object literal syntax:

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
    provideRouter(routes, SpyLocation),
    MyTestComponent,
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
    {provide: ContentService, useClass: MockContentService})
]));
```